# to get a KeyValuePair from a List of KeyvaluePairs with the minimum value

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get a Kvp from a list of `List<KeyValuePair<Int, Int>>` depending on the minimum value.

I have tried this:

```
KeyValuePair<Int, Int> kvp= listOfKvps.Min(e=> e.Key);
```

but this return only the value, not the whole `KeyValuePair` which I need.

Comment: that statement seems contradictory.  If you didn't get back the KeyValuePair, that code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Dave - but it clearly depicts what the OP wants to do. I'd **much rather** have an example that doesn't compile but shows intent, than an example that compiles but doesn't help understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inbuilt `MinBy` method, so you could *either* write a `MinBy` extension method, or just `.OrderBy(x => x.Key).First()`. A `MinBy` would be `O(n)` so would be more efficient - but more code to write ;p

For example, you could use:

```
var kvp= listOfKvps.MinBy(e=> e.Key);
```

with:

```
public static class SomeUtil {
    public static TSource MinBy<TSource, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
        using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!iter.MoveNext()) throw new InvalidOperationException("no data");
            var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
            var minItem = iter.Current;
            var minValue = selector(minItem);
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                var item = iter.Current;
                var value = selector(item);
                if (comparer.Compare(minValue, value) > 0)
                {
                    minItem = item;
                    minValue = value;
                }
            }
            return minItem;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: No more code to write if you use MoreLINQ: morelinq.googlecode.com :)

Comment: [Rx](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Extensible-XML.aspx) does add a MinBy extension methods in the `EnumerableEx` class. So one can hope for a future version of the Framework.

Answer (score 6):

```
var min = listOfKvps.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).First();
```

If you want to do it with a single *O(n)* pass through the sequence, rather than requiring an *O(n log n)* ordering, then you could do it like this:

```
var min = listOfKvps.Aggregate((agg, kvp) => (kvp.Key < agg.Key) ? kvp : agg);
```

(Of course, the second version is much less readable/intuitive than the first, even if it does have better theoretical performance. It would make more sense to use some sort of `MinBy` method: either write your own, [use the version from Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205670/to-get-a-keyvaluepair-from-a-list-of-keyvaluepairs-with-the-minimun-value/4205710#4205710) or [use the version from MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).)

Comment: Note that ordering is O(n lg n) in time and O(n) in space; you can fetch the min in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @Eric: Very true. I was going to edit that in immediately after I posted the original answer but for some reason was logged out of SO and couldn't get back in until now!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use the `MinBy` extension-method from [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Alternatively:

```
var minKey = listOfKvps.Min(kvp => kvp.Key);
var minKvp = listOfKvps.First(kvp => kvp.Key == minKey);
```

This is still `O(n)`, although it requires 2 passes over the list. Sorting the list and then picking the first element is more terse, but is `O(n * logn)`, which may be relevant for larger lists.